# Why does alt_user_path(@user) link to user_path(@user)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, path, routes

I have two seperate views for a model `User`, one called `show` and the other called `alt`. I'm trying to build a link on the `show` view that links to the `alt` view, but for some reason it just links back to the `show` view. `Show` is just defined by the standard resourceful routes paths.

**routes.rb**:

```
get "users/:id_alt", :to => "users#alt", :as => :alt_user
resources :users
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**:

```
<%= link_to "Alt", alt_user_path(@user) %>
```

For example, on the show view for users/2, the above link links back to users/2. How can I get it to link to users/2_alt?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. `alt` should be a member action on `User`, and the path would be `/users/2/alt`. Embedding a parameter in the middle of a URL seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the route not working correctly is because the :id_alt specifies an attribute of the users model. For example, if you typed users.id_alt in the console for model with an ID of 2, would you expect to return "2_alt"?

I would suggest routing to users/2/alt as it's more RESTful. However, if you're dead set on users/2_alt maybe check into string interpolation #{}.

Comment: Would the full routes code be something other than this then: `get "users/:id/alt", :to => "users#alt", :as => :alt_user` ? Because that's still just routing to users/:id.

Comment: If you use :as => :alt_user your route is not going to know what :alt_user is going to be. Why :id works is because if you have a model (say User) and call "id" on it (User.id) you will get 2 (or whatever the ID of the user is). If for some reason you have :alt_user saved as an attribute in the DB then :as => :alt_user WILL work but then your going to have routing errors as then the route will then be /2 (or whatever User.alt_user) equals to in the database.

Comment: So how can I successfully route to users/2/alt?

Comment: But `users/:id/alt` currently just routes to `users/:id`. How can I make it a seperate route with its own path?

Comment: You would need to use resources; 
resources :users do 
  resources :alt
end

Answer (score 0):

The correct routing for what you want is:

```
resources :users do
  get 'alt', on: :member
end
```

You can then use `<%= link_to 'Alt', alt_user_path(@user) %>` and it will make a ink like `/users/2/alt` and use the controller action `UsersController#alt`.

Comment: How does `:member` factor in?

Comment: The `:member` tells it that it is a route on a specific user. So a specific user would be `/users/2` and the 'alt' route for that user would be `/users/2/alt`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have a route like `/users/2_alt`, you'd need to configure the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def to_param
       id + "_alt"
   end
end
```

Edit: 
I didn't quite understand your question before so allow me to update my answer.

This obviously would map the /user/2_alt to the show action. I guess then your best shoot if you want to continue this way is to add logic in the controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController 
   def show
       if params[:id] =~ /\d_alt/
           # alt action logic
       else
           # show action logic
       end
   end
end
```